# Buridan's principle in computable analysis

Tags: real-analysis, computational-complexity, computability-theory, computer-science, computable-analysis

In (Lamport, 2012), Lamport proposes the principle

> A discrete decision based upon an input
>   having a continuous range of values cannot be made within a bounded length of time.

I think it could be formalized in computable analysis somehow. First attempt:

> Let $\mathbb{R}_c$ be the set of computable real numbers, and let $T$ be any Turing machine computing a function $f: \mathbb{R}_c \to \{0, 1\}$, then there exists some $r_c\in \mathbb{R}_c$, such that as $r\to r_c$, the runtime of $T(r)\to \infty$.

This fails because all computable functions are continuous. So my second attempt is:

> Let $T_n$ be a sequence of Turing machine computing a sequence of functions $f_n: \mathbb{R}_c \to [0, 1]$, such that $f_n(r) = 0$ for all $r < -1/n$ and $f_n(r) = 1$ for all $r > 1/n$, the runtime of $T_n(0)\to \infty$ as $n\to \infty$.

Does some theorem like this exist?

*Lamport, Leslie*, [**Buridan’s principle**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10701-012-9647-7),  [ZBL06122531](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:06122531).

Comment: “The runtime of $T_n(0)$” is a function, eg “for an accuracy of 1/10 run for this many steps and for an accuracy of 1/100 run for this many steps.” How then should we interpret the concluding convergence?

Comment: I think you are making it too complicated. The principle is formalized by “every computable function $\mathbb R\to\{0,1\}$ is constant”.